# ctype_digit validation fails passing 0 with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, isnumeric

I have the following situation:

```
<select name="n">
    <option>Please fill</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Now, i pass the serialized form with Ajax. I correctly see this in the console's POST panel:

```
[...]&n=0&[...]
```

My php validation script check both if the field has been filled and, for security reasons, that it is a digit:

```
parse_str($_REQUEST['data'], $values);
if (!ctype_digit($values['n'])) {
    array_push($err, 'n');
}
```

Can someone explain WHY if i'm passing the value 0 this check always fails? If i pass any other select option with a digit other than 0, it let me in...
I tried also using is_numeric instead of ctype_digit (just to try) and it fails as well. But this makes no sense...as 0 is both numeric and digit!

**UPDATE**
if i `var_dump($values['n'])`, i get that it is null...so is there any problem with the `parse_str($_REQUEST['data'], $values)`?

Comment: The `!` character itself is a negation, not a comparison. To @deceze answer I'd also add `intval()` somewhere.

Comment: @DanFromGermany why shuld i add intval() when ctype_digit() already returns false on all entry that are not digits (including float numbers both with dot or comma)?

Answer (score 3):

Both `0` and `'0'` (as integer and as string) are considered `false`. So `!$values['n']` is `true`. `ctype_digit` works just fine. You probably want to check for `!isset($values['n'])` instead of `!$values['n']`.

Comment: thanks, it worked with isset but with var_dump($values['n']) it says me that it is null...so i guess the problem is in the parse_str()?

Comment: Why aren't you using `$_GET['n']`/`$_POST['n']` to begin with...?

Comment: cause my form is a lot more complex then the part i've posted and with the parse_str i get all the variables with only 1 line of code. also, as `data` is a string passed by ajax, i can't use $_POST